# Const Member Variables in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

code

```
   category::category ( const std::string p_name , std::string p_ImagePath) :
    m_name { p_name },
    m_ImagePath {p_ImagePath }
    {

    }
```

header

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class category
{
public:
    const int i;
    explicit category ( const std::string p_name ,const std::string p_ImagePath);
    ~category ( );
    std::string GetName ( );
private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_ImagePath;
};
```

I allways get errors due to assignment opperator

Fehler  1   error C2280: 'booking &booking::operator =(const booking &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2013 CTP\include\utility   53

if i try to use a const member variable or a const static member variable in a class.

```
I tried const i = 5;
static const i = 5;
and const i; -> i gets initialized in constructor.
```

Nothing works, how can i fix this? 
And i cant use constexpr due to vs2013 does not assist it :(

I already checked some questions on Stackoverflow but everything was with constexpr

Comment: if it could be changed on copy, then it's not const, then why you insist on making `i` const?

Comment: Your code doesn't even have `booking` anywhere in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the copy assignment operator explicitly. As your `class` has a `const`, non-`static` data member then the compiler defined copy assignment operator is deleted.

Also it is totally unclear what is the meaning of that `const`, non-`static` data member in your `class` definition.

As for the constructor, you may remove function specifier `explicit` and define the parameters as constant references.

```
category( const std::string &p_name, const std::string &p_ImagePath );
```