# How to set a const member variable in a C++ class on construction?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, constants, member

Well this might question might have a fair amount of overlap with these questions:

[how to initialize const member variable in a class C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495536/how-to-initialize-const-member-variable-in-a-class-c)
[Const Member Variables in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342656/const-member-variables-in-c11)
[Initializing a const member variable after object construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458512/initializing-a-const-member-variable-after-object-construction)

Yet, none of these could answer my original question. The main difference being that I do not want to initialize with a set value but with a constructor parameter.

What I want to do is something like this-

```
class myRectangle {
private:
   const int length;  //const mainly for "read-only" like
   const int breadth;  //protection
public:
   myRectangle(int init_length, int init_breadth);
   int calcArea(void);
   void turn90Degrees(void);
  /* and so on*/
```

}

where both length and breadth are kinda read-only protected from altering them after construction.
But of course my compiler won't allow me to set them in the constructor because they are in fact const...
I did come up with the workaround to just leave them variable and only implement getter methods so they cannot effectively be changed but I pretty much feel like I am missing the obvious solution here.

Also I feel like I misunderstood the use of const to some degree. So is it "already" a compile-time contract to not alter the data from there on? Because in my understanding isn't knowing the size the constant takes in the execution of the program enough information?

*And btw the solution of making the constant static would not fit for me because every rectangle I spawn should have a different size.*

Thank you for your answers and clarifications!

**Solution**: Intializer Lists / delegating constructors

[MSDN Entry of the solution from Jason R](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn387583.aspx)

Comment: "But of course my compiler won't allow me to set them in the constructor because they are in fact const..." Of course it will. Just make sure you *initialize* them, not assign to them.

Comment: Can you explain *why* [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14495536/3953764) does not answer yours ?

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki Because he wants to initialize the const with a set value (in his case the 100) - I for myself do not know in my program what value it will have

Comment: @Saltus replace `100` with a constructor parameter name

Comment: @Piotr well, yes. Thanks. If I would have known before that it could be so "easy" I wouldn't have asked the question, you know...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an initializer list in the constructor.

```
class myRectangle {
private:
   const int length;  //const mainly for "read-only" like
   const int breadth;  //protection
public:
   myRectangle(int init_length, int init_breadth) : 
       length(init_length), breadth(init_breadth) 
   { 
       // rest of constructor body can go here; `length` and `breadth`
       // are already initialized by the time you get here
   }
   int calcArea(void);
   void turn90Degrees(void);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Somehow I need to get used to the stackoverflow search function better. Now twice soon after I post my question that bothers me for days I end up finding an answer to it. Because I wasn't aware of the term "delegated constructors" and never heard of an initializer list in that regard I did not know what to look for. If you search for a "bicycle with an engine" you somehow appear to have a hard time finding a "motorcycle" ...

Comment: But as for your answer: Is it possible to declare constructor body outside of the class declaration? And if so how would it look like?

Comment: @Saltus `myRectangle::myRectangle(int init_length, int init_breadth) : length(init_length), breadth(init_breadth) {}`